# How to load only profile specific property file and ignore default application.properties?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-profiles

I have a normal spring boot application, and two property files in `resources` folder:

*application.properties*

```
com.example.prop1=value1
com.example.enableMock=true
```

*application-dev.properties*

```
com.example.prop1=value11
```

I have some logic based on whether `com.example.enableMock` is present or missing. Problem is spring loads both files even if `spring.profiles.active=dev` and the application is getting the `com.example.enableMock` property.

How do I just load profile specific property file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default `application.properties` is loaded for any `application-*.properties` because is shared by following way:

```
application.properties
     - > application-dev.properties
     - > application-test.properties
```

You can fix this if you put `default` as profile. 
Rename `application.properties` to:

```
application-default.properties
```