# How to ignore application.properties values if profile set without changing to application-default.properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-profiles

I am using spring profiles to load configurations based on the environment and when reading using Autowired Environment object, it seems additional to environment specific values, Spring also pass values from application.properties, the same is mentioned in spring document [Profile-specific Properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties) and also here in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54191398/2151491), but I cannot change to application-default.properties because of below limitation.

The problem/limitation for me is the deployment platform(rules) that I am using, for all environment the environment the identifier will be passed as JVM arguments, but for production it will not be passed, as mentioned below

```
application-dev.properties --> DEV environment will pass this -Dspring.profiles.active=dev
application-qa.properties --> QA environment will pass this -Dspring.profiles.active=qa
application.properties --> PROD environment won't pass any argument
```

The option I am having now is to have keys in application.properties with empty values in other environment specific properties file(event not used)and handle in code, other than this is there any other elegant way to handle without change application.properties

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the linked documentation ([Profile-specific Properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties)) says, `application.properties` is always loaded.

As it also says, if no active profile has been set (e.g. using `-Dspring.profiles.active`), the `default` profile is automatically made active.

As the section [Adding Active Profiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-adding-active-profiles) says, you can have a profile-specific property add active profiles with the `spring.profiles.include` property.

This means that you can have the `default` profile property file activate a `prod` profile, like this:

*File `application-default.properties`:*

```
spring.profiles.include = prod
```

If you have that file, then running without `-Dspring.profiles.active` set will load properties from these files (in order):

```
application-prod.properties
application-default.properties
application.properties
```

If you run with `-Dspring.profiles.active=dev`, properties are loaded from these files (in order):

```
application-dev.properties
application.properties
```

By doing that, you now have a well-named profile-specific property file for each of your environments:

```
application-dev.properties  --> since DEV environment passed -Dspring.profiles.active=dev
application-qa.properties   --> since QA environment passed -Dspring.profiles.active=qa
application-prod.properties --> since PROD environment didn't pass -Dspring.profiles.active
```

The `application.properties` file is still loaded, and should contain all non-environment-specific properties, i.e. all **common** properties, as well as *default* values for any global properties that might have environment-specific values (overrides).

The `application-<profile>.properties` files can add environment-specific properties, and can override global properties that needs a different value than the default specified in the `application.properties` file.

Comment: thanks, this work perfectly, but I need to check if it is allowed to have application-default.properties additionally, may I ask you this, why is it not working if I include profile in application.properties because as spring both property files are same

Comment: @java_dev What do you mean? If I add `spring.profiles.include = foo` to `application.properties`, then profile `foo` is active too.

Comment: if add spring.profiles.include = prod to application.properties, then prod is additionally added to JVM argument supplied profile, but if I add prod to application-default.properties only JVM argument supplied profile is active and prod is active only when there is no argument

Comment: @java_dev Your first comment was asking *"why is it not working if I include profile in application.properties"*, but it *is* working, i.e. putting the "include" property in `application.properties` *will* activate the `prod` profile. Since `application.properties` is **always** processed, that means the `prod` profile is *always* activated, even when another profile is activated using command-line option, but when command-line option is given, `application-default.properties` is not processed, so putting the property there makes it only include `prod` by **default**. It's all in the answer.